# print()関数で \xe3\x81\x82〜 のように出力されてしまう

Tags: python, python3

初心者用の本で年を入れると干支がわかるプログラムを書いているのですが

```
year_str = input('あなたの生まれ年の西暦を４桁で入力してください: ')
year = int(year_str)
number_of_eto = (year + 8) % 12
print('あなたの干支は', number_of_eto, '番です。')
```

と書くと
あなたの生まれ年の西暦を４桁で入力してください: 
と出て年を入力すると

```
('\xe3\x81\x82\xe3\x81\xaa\xe3\x81\x9f\xe3\x81\xae\xe5\xb9\xb2\xe6\x94\xaf\xe3\x81\xaf', 2, '\xe7\x95\xaa\xe3\x81\xa7\xe3\x81\x99\xe3\x80\x82')
```

と出てしまいます。

本だとあなたの干支は〜番ですと出るはずなのですが、どこか書き方が間違っていますか❓

Comment: 言語タグで`python3`を指定されているようですが、現在使われているpythonの正確なバージョンはわかりますか?python 3.6.0ではあなたのコードは期待通りに動きました。printの挙動はpythonのバージョンによって変わるのでそのせいだと思います。

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 をお使いなのであれば、このコードで正しく出力されるはずです。しかし Python 2 では質問文にあるようにバックスラッシュでエスケープされたものがたくさんある文字列が出力されます。これは、Python 3.0 から[プログラム中にある文字列のエンコードの扱いが変わった](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.7/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit)ことと関係しています。

ということで、まずはお使いの Python のバージョンをご確認ください。これはたとえばターミナルで以下のコマンドを入力すると確かめられます。

```
python --version
```

Python 2.x がインストールされていれば、それが原因です。解決法はいくつかあります。

- `python3` コマンドが存在すれば、`python` コマンドの代わりにこれを使う。これは Python 3.x 系を動かすためのコマンドです。
- 今後 2.x 系を使う予定が無いのであれば、一度 2.x を削除して 3.x をインストールする。これのやり方は OS やパッケージ管理ツールによって異なります。やり方が分からなければ別途ご質問ください。

Comment: 今回の挙動はprintが文から関数に変わったことによるもので、文字列の問題とは直接の関係はないように思います。python2の場合(正確に2から3のどの時点で切り替わったのかよくわかりませんが)print文に括弧付きの引数を渡すと、タプルとして扱われるため、タプルの出力型式で出力されているのだと思われます。

Comment: python 2.7.10でも、括弧を使わず `print 'あなたの干支は', number_of_eto, '番です。'` のように書くとエスケープ形式で表示されることはありません。

Comment: まだ右も左もあんまりわかってない初心者に親切な回答ありがとうございます。（）を取ってみると動いてくれました！！

Comment: @松永直也 さん、無事に動かせるようになったということで良かったです。できればご自身で「回答」を投稿してみませんか。また、nekketsuuu さんの回答にある方法でバージョン番号を確かめてみられたのであれば、その内容もおしらせくださると嬉しいです。